# Cannot see MySQL tables after moving database dir with symbolic link

Tags: mysql, symlink

I'm running out of space on the partition where MySQL is installed so I tried moving my largest database to a new partition and symlinked this in the data directory. When I try to use this database I get the following error

```
mysql> use fb20;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './fb20/' (errno: 13)
```

I've checked that symlinks are enabled:

```
mysql> show variables like 'have_symlink';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| have_symlink  | YES   |
+---------------+-------+
```

All of the permissions look correct. The MySQL data directory is `/data`:

```
root> ll /data/
drwxr-x--- 243 mysql    mysql      8192 Feb 21 08:02 mysql/

root> ll /data/mysql/ | grep fb20
lrwxrwxrwx   1 mysql mysql           19 Feb 21 08:02 fb20 -> /sandata/mysql/fb20/
```

and the new directory is `/sandata`:

```
root> ll /sandata/
drwxr-x---  3 mysql    mysql               60 Feb 20 20:32 mysql/

root> ll /sandata/mysql/
total 360
drwxr-x---  3 mysql mysql     60 Feb 20 20:32 ./
drwxrwxr-x 35 root  perma   4096 Feb 20 19:59 ../
drwx------  2 mysql mysql 303104 Feb 15 12:20 fb20/
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Based on my past experience, my guess (and its just a guess) is that the issue is related to the configuration of **AppArmor**  (The AppArmor profile may only be allowing read/write access to matching paths.)

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment I added the following lines to the file `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

```
/sandata/mysql/ r,
/sandata/mysql/** rwk,
```

and then reloaded the profile (restarting apparmor did not work):

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Comment: An alternative to modifying the profile is to add an "alias" rule...   http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference#Alias_and_rewrite_rules